How can I run Anti Aliasing and Post Process together in Directx 9?
I am facing a very strange problem. I have a project that I use with Directx9 and C++. In this project, I add and run external shaders via post processing. But I have a problem: if I enable the antialiasing flag while creating the d3d device, post processing does not work and the screen becomes pitch black. There is no error log either. If I remove the antialiasing flag when creating the device, everything works fine.
But even without anti-aliasing, the image quality looks very bad. Aren't these two compatible with each other? Or am I missing something?
Device creation flags:
ZeroMemory(&ms_d3dPresentParameter, sizeof(ms_d3dPresentParameter));

ms_d3dPresentParameter.Windowed                         = Windowed;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferWidth                  = iHres;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferHeight                 = iVres;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.hDeviceWindow                    = hWnd;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferCount                  = m_uBackBufferCount;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.SwapEffect                       = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;

if (Windowed)
{
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat             = pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetDesktopD3DDisplayModer().Format;
}
else
{
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat             = pkD3DModeInfo->m_eD3DFmtPixel;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz   = iReflashRate;
}

//ms_d3dPresentParameter.Flags                          = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.EnableAutoDepthStencil           = TRUE;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.AutoDepthStencilFormat           = pkD3DModeInfo->m_eD3DFmtDepthStencil;

ms_dwD3DBehavior = pkD3DModeInfo->m_dwD3DBehavior;
ms_bEnableGlobalAntialiasing = false;

if (antialias) // if true..
{
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES; // yes.
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
}

And Post-Processing:
bool CPostProcessingChain::CreateResources()
{
    ReleaseResources();

    D3DSURFACE_DESC kDesc;
    IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface);
    pSurface->GetDesc(&kDesc);
    pSurface->Release();

    //  constexpr auto kTextureFormat = D3DFMT_A16B16G16R16F;
    constexpr auto kTextureFormat = D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F;

    if (FAILED(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->CreateTexture(kDesc.Width, kDesc.Height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, kTextureFormat, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_lpSourceTexture, nullptr)))
    {
        TraceError("CPostProcessingChain unable to create render target");
        return false;
    }
    m_lpSourceTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &m_lpSourceTextureSurface);
    if (FAILED(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->CreateTexture(kDesc.Width, kDesc.Height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, kTextureFormat, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_lpLastPass, nullptr)))
    {
        TraceError("CPostProcessingChain unable to create pass render target");
        return false;
    }
    m_lpLastPass->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &m_lpLastPassSurface);
    if (FAILED(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->CreateTexture(kDesc.Width, kDesc.Height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, kTextureFormat, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_lpTarget, nullptr)))
    {
        TraceError("CPostProcessingChain unable to create final render target");
        return false;
    }
    m_lpTarget->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &m_lpTargetSurface);

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetDepthStencilSurface(&pSurface);
    pSurface->GetDesc(&kDesc);
    pSurface->Release();
    if (FAILED(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->CreateDepthStencilSurface(kDesc.Width, kDesc.Height, D3DFMT_D16, kDesc.MultiSampleType, kDesc.MultiSampleQuality, FALSE, &m_lpDepthStencilSurface, nullptr)))
    {
        TraceError("CPostProcessingChain unable to create depth surface");
        return false;
    }

    if (FAILED(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(TRTTVertex) * 6, 0, D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_TEX1, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &m_lpScreenQuad, nullptr)))
    {
        TraceError("CPostProcessingChain unable to create screen quad");
        return false;
    }

    float fWidth = static_cast<float>(kDesc.Width) - 0.5f;
    float fHeight = static_cast<float>(kDesc.Height) - 0.5f;

    TRTTVertex* pVertices;
    m_lpScreenQuad->Lock(0, 0, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVertices), 0);
    pVertices[0].p = D3DXVECTOR4(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[0].t = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    pVertices[1].p = D3DXVECTOR4(-0.5f, fHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[1].t = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[2].p = D3DXVECTOR4(fWidth, fHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[2].t = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[3].p = D3DXVECTOR4(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[3].t = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    pVertices[4].p = D3DXVECTOR4(fWidth, fHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[4].t = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[5].p = D3DXVECTOR4(fWidth, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    pVertices[5].t = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_lpScreenQuad->Unlock();

    time_t curr_time;
    curr_time = time(nullptr);
    tm* tm_local = localtime(&curr_time);

    return true;
}

bool CPostProcessingChain::BeginScene()
{
    if (!m_lpSourceTexture || !m_lpLastPass || !m_lpTarget || !m_lpDepthStencilSurface)
    {
        if (!CreateResources())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    time_t curr_time;
    curr_time = time(nullptr);
    tm* tm_local = localtime(&curr_time);

    if (Frustum::Instance().isChangingSky == true)
    {
        UpdateEffect();
        Frustum::Instance().refreshEffect = true;
    }
    
    if (Frustum::Instance().updatePostProcessing)
    {
        UpdateEffect();
    }

    

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetRenderTarget(0, &m_lpBackupTargetSurface);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetRenderTarget(0, m_lpSourceTextureSurface);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetDepthStencilSurface(&m_lpDepthStencilBackup);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetDepthStencilSurface(m_lpDepthStencilSurface);

    return true;
}
bool CPostProcessingChain::EndScene()
{
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetRenderTarget(0, m_lpBackupTargetSurface);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetDepthStencilSurface(m_lpDepthStencilBackup);
    if (m_lpDepthStencilBackup)
    {
        m_lpDepthStencilBackup->Release();
        m_lpDepthStencilBackup = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpBackupTargetSurface)
    {
        m_lpBackupTargetSurface->Release();
        m_lpBackupTargetSurface = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpDepthStencilSurface)
    {
        m_lpDepthStencilSurface->Release();
        m_lpDepthStencilSurface = nullptr;
    }
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetPixelShader(nullptr);

    return true;
}



bool CPostProcessingChain::Render()
{
    D3DXMATRIX mWorld, mView, mProj, mIdentity;
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&mIdentity);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &mWorld);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &mView);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &mProj);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &mIdentity);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &mIdentity);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &mIdentity);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetRenderTarget(0, m_lpLastPassSurface);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, FALSE);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS, TRUE);

    //STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->Clear(0, nullptr, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0.0f);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->Clear(0, nullptr, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0.0f);

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTexture(0, m_lpSourceTexture);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetPixelShader(nullptr);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetVertexShader(nullptr);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_TEX1);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetStreamSource(0, m_lpScreenQuad, 0, sizeof(TRTTVertex));
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 2);

    IDirect3DSurface9* pCurrentTarget = m_lpTargetSurface;

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTexture(1, m_lpSourceTexture);

    for (std::list<CPostProcessingEffect>::iterator it = m_kEffects.begin(); it != m_kEffects.end(); ++it)
    {
        D3DSURFACE_DESC kDesc;
        pCurrentTarget->GetDesc(&kDesc);

        D3DXVECTOR4 vScreenSize = D3DXVECTOR4(kDesc.Width, kDesc.Height, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        (*it).GetConstants()->SetFloatArray(STATEMANAGER.GetDevice(), "ScreenSize", reinterpret_cast<float*>(&vScreenSize), 4);

        if (Frustum::Instance().dynamicLight == 2)
        {
            if ((*it).Apply())
            {
                STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetRenderTarget(0, pCurrentTarget);
                STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->Clear(0, nullptr, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0.0f);
                STATEMANAGER.SetTexture(0, pCurrentTarget == m_lpLastPassSurface ? m_lpTarget : m_lpLastPass);
                STATEMANAGER.SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_TEX1);
                STATEMANAGER.SetStreamSource(0, m_lpScreenQuad, sizeof(TRTTVertex));
                STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 2);
                pCurrentTarget = pCurrentTarget == m_lpLastPassSurface ? m_lpTargetSurface : m_lpLastPassSurface;
            }
        }
    }

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTexture(1, nullptr);

    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetRenderTarget(0, m_lpBackupTargetSurface);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTexture(0, pCurrentTarget == m_lpLastPassSurface ? m_lpTarget : m_lpLastPass);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_TEX1);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetStreamSource(0, m_lpScreenQuad, 0, sizeof(TRTTVertex));
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 2);

    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &mWorld);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &mView);
    STATEMANAGER.GetDevice()->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &mProj);

    return true;
}
void CPostProcessingChain::ReleaseResources()
{
    if (m_lpLastPassSurface)
    {
        m_lpLastPassSurface->Release();
        m_lpLastPassSurface = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpSourceTextureSurface)
    {
        m_lpSourceTextureSurface->Release();
        m_lpSourceTextureSurface = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpTargetSurface)
    {
        m_lpTargetSurface->Release();
        m_lpTargetSurface = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpSourceTexture)
    {
        m_lpSourceTexture->Release();
        m_lpSourceTexture = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpLastPass)
    {
        m_lpLastPass->Release();
        m_lpLastPass = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpTarget)
    {
        m_lpTarget->Release();
        m_lpTarget = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpDepthStencilSurface)
    {
        m_lpDepthStencilSurface->Release();
        m_lpDepthStencilSurface = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_lpScreenQuad)
    {
        m_lpScreenQuad->Release();
        m_lpScreenQuad = nullptr;
    }
}


Upon seeing constexpr auto kTextureFormat I have questions: Why in the world are you using modern C++17 to write code using a 25+ year old graphics API that hasn't had debugging support of any form since Windows 7? IOW: Why are you not using DirectX 11 for this project? Also, if you are comfortable using C++17, why are you not using a COM smart-pointer like Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr rather than relying on manual error-prone ref-counting?

I don't know exactly where your bug is or if it's even in the code above, but generally you render to an MSAA render target, resolve MSAA render targets to a single sample before doing post-processing, and then place the final result in a single-sample swapchain/backbuffer. You may find this blog post useful.
